# Have connection strings as well as common config source in asp.net or wcf websites

Tags: asp.net, wcf, connection-string

Hi I am looking for a solution where I have some common connection strings which I have
a common connections strings file but also need some specific add and remove connection strings in some sites...but do not see a way to do it...

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings configSource="connections.config">
    <remove name="AppConnectionString" />
    <add name="AppConnectionString" connectionString="data source=(local);initial     catalog=xyz;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" />
  <connectionStrings/> 
</configuration>
```

With file connections.config containing

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="name" connectionString="conn_string" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="name2" connectionString="conn_string2" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Thanks,
Bala

Answer (score 0):

If this does not work as you have expressed it above (which is a shame in my opinon), you have a number of other options:

1. Include the common connection strings in the connection string config, and then use the application settings config for the app-specific connection strings.
2. As an alternative, use a custom configuration file for the app-specific connection strings and load it in for each app.
3. When you build your apps inject the correct connection string keys into the config file using something like powershell. This script can run as a post build task in your build script.
4. Otherwise, when you package or stage your release, ask the release team to run the script as a manual step (or add it into your deployment script).